# Javascript Synchronous Calls

Tags: javascript

I have a function, that gets called twice by an `observe` function.  As you can see, in the `addMessage` function, there is a check that if it is called with the same messge, it `return`s.

My problem is, that the `addMessage` function is getting called twice with the same message.

I think the reason is because it is being done quickly before the first message has been added, the second message is executed already.

What is the best way to synchronize the messages, that the first one is given time to save, before the second one is processed?

```
  this.messages.observe({
    changed: (newMessage, oldMessage) => this.addMessage(newMessage)
  });
```

and

```
  private addMessage(message: Message): void {
    let foundMessage: Message = this.localMessageCollection.findOne({ _id: message._id });
    if (foundMessage && foundMessage._id === message._id) {
    console.log('addMessage(found): '+message._id+'   '+message.content);
      return;
    }
    console.log('addMessage: '+message._id+'   '+message.content);
    this.addLocalMessage(message);
    this.chatsStorageService.addMessage(this.activeChat, message).then((messageData: Message) => {
      let data = {
        chat: this.activeChat,
        messageString: this.messageString,
        sendMessage: true
      }
      this.events.publish('messages:update', data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what `localMessageCollection` is exactly, but does it support an atomic `upsert` operation, or something to that effect? Instead of a race-condition-prone *check-then-insert*, do an *insert-if-not-exists*.

Comment: Otherwise you simply keep a local array of messages not yet processed… `if (this.messagesInProgress.indexOf(message) > -1) { return; }`

Comment: I wonder why `findOne` is synchronous but `addMessage` isn't…

Comment: What does `addLocalMessage` do? Isn't it synchronous?

Comment: It just adds the message to an array. Just a one liner

Comment: `localMessageCollection` is a `Mongo.Collection<Message>`

Comment: I think I will keep an array of processed messages unless someone suggests a better answer for now

Comment: @Richard Is it the `localMessageCollection` one? In that case, your code should work already. Maybe post the definitions of `addLocalMessage` and `findOne`.

Comment: You will want to have a look at [Limit concurrency of promise being run](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38778723/1048572)

Comment: Yes, `this.localMessageCollection` is being updated, but I think the second message is entering before the update is completed.