# What is a good pattern for waiting until x number of promises are completed to spawn a new promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout, es6-promise

I have been searching and have found some variations of this but have not found anything that meets my needs exactly. Below is the pseudocode that I am trying to figure out:

```
var itemsUploading = 0;
const maxUploads = 10;


function uploadAll(items){
    var promises = [];
    items.forEach(function(item){

        /* Here is where I want to wait for itemsCurrentlyUploading < maxUploads */

        itemsUploading++;            
        promises.push(upload(item));            
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);

}

function upload(item){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        /*Item upload logic here */

    })
    .then(function(response){
        itemsUploading--;
    });
}
```

I do understand that you cannot block synchronous code to wait for asynchronous and I have tried several variations. I think `setTimeout` is something that I can use to do this but I can't quite understand the logic necessary. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated and if there is anything else I can edit this with to help someone understand the problem better just let me know, thank you!

Comment: You need to read up on chaining Promises and Deferred calls, keyword here is `.then()`

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39197252/1048572) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38778887/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may find something like [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html#map-option-concurrency) from Bluebird library useful. `concurrency` parameter allows you to set maximum number of "pending" promises.

Simple solution, but I guess not as battle-tested as Bluebird, is available as [standalone NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-concurrency).

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is a little sparse on the data structures, we'll have to make do.

```
let pending = new Set;
let maxPendingItems = 5; // could be whatever number

let wrapPromiseFn = f => (...args) => {
  let p = f(...args);
  pending.add(p);
  p
    .then(() => pending.remove(p))
    .catch(e => {
      console.warn(e);
      pending.remove(p);
    });

  return p;
};

let performAsyncIO = wrapPromiseFn(someAJAXFn);
```

Now you can have a loop that monitors the size of the set to see if it has cleared out enough to add new items. Just make sure that you decorate your Promise-returning functions with `wrapPromiseFn` like above.

```
let flag = true;
while (flag) {
  if (pending.size <= maxPendingItems) {
    // promise will automatically queue until resolved
    performAsyncIO().then(responseHandler);
  }
}
```